# How on the Linux platform can I find out what port my web browser is using to receive packets from a web server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, browser, port

When the web server sends data back to the browser, the browser receives that data using a particular port on my system. How can I find out what that port is on a Linux machine?

Comment: Not it isn't. The browser isn't 'listening'. It is *connected* via a local port. Hard to see what good knowing that port number is going to do you, but you can see it with `netstat`.

Comment: @EJP he said "receiving" not "listening". And the client (browser) does indeed receive packets using the source port it used when establishing the connection. The TCP connection is characterized by 4 parameters: source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port. As for why it could be needed the answer is typically "for capturing the traffic".

Comment: Use `netstat` or, better, `lsof`

Comment: Well, `netstat` produces a lot of output. What exactly should my arguments to `netstat` be?

Comment: @kikap He said 'listening', not 'receiving'. Check the edit history. And I didn't say anything about the browser not using the original source port. Don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -tp` will provide the list of TCP connections with addresses and ports in symbolic form (IPs resolved to hostnames and ports resolved to service names) along with the names of the programs, while `netstat -tpn` will return the same but with ports and IPs in numeric form.